# To divide a circle into different regions for a dart board?

Tags: android, c++, iphone, ios, math

[image: Dart board]

Can some one point me in the right direction on how I can divide a circle to get different regions for a dart board?

Comment: +1 just for the wonderful graphic.

Comment: ^ Thanks a lot mate... You saved a lot trouble today!!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're using a cylindrical coordinate system: it's best to express everything in terms of (r, theta) instead of (x, y).

Here's how the two are related:

```
x = r*cos(theta)
y = r*sin(theta)
```

If you do that it's easy.

I see seven different radii and twenty angular sections, so each angular section has to be 18 degrees each.

The angular section around the 20 is centered about the vertical.  Pick a line for `theta = 0` and start from there.  (Two good choices might be horizontal to the right or the center of the 20.)

Just one caveat: Remember that computers usually implement trig functions to take radians, not degrees.  360 degrees in a circle is intuitive for most people, but computers will prefer 2π radians.